# Cannot find a way to switch scenes with a button from class JavaFX

Tags: java, class, javafx, scene, stage

I'm trying to make a my scene switch to another when you click my button
My problem is in my second button in my class I am not sure what to put in it, I can't set the stage from inside that button because it is in another method I need to set about 10 different scenes, very confused any help is appreciated its a school culminating -_-. (If there is any better way to make a program that changes picture please inform me thank you!)

```
public class MainStage extends Application  {
    SceneSwitch switcher1= new SceneSwitch();

      MediaPlayer mp3;

      String i="file:///C://NetbeanFiles//plane.jpg";

      Image pic=new Image(i); 


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Media musicfile=new Media("file:///C://NetbeanFiles//Stereo.mp3");
        mp3= new MediaPlayer(musicfile);
        mp3.setAutoPlay(true);
        mp3.setVolume(0.05);


       ImageView view = new ImageView(pic);

       Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

               primaryStage.setScene(switcher1.Switcher());

            }
        });


        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(view);

        btn.setPadding(new Insets(10 ,10, 10, 10));
        pane.setTop(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1920, 1080);

        //how to keep button centered last number is X

        pane.setMargin(btn, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 875));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}





//End of MAINSTAGE

//Start of SCENESWITCH class





 public class SceneSwitch {
        int j=0;
         String i="file:///C://NetbeanFiles//planet.jpg";
    ArrayList<String> Hello= new ArrayList<String>(); 


    public SceneSwitch(){
        Hello.add("file:///C://NetbeanFiles//planet.jpg");
        `Hello.add("file:///C://NetbeanFiles//download.jpg");
     }




    public Scene Switcher(){


      ImageView view = new ImageView(Hello.get(j));

       Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            //**HERE IS MY PROBLEM NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT IN HERE**
            }
        });


        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        pane.setCenter(view);

        btn.setPadding(new Insets(10 ,10, 10, 10));
        pane.setTop(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1920, 1080);

        //how to keep button centered last number is X

        pane.setMargin(btn, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 875));


     return scene; 
    }




}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, but if the problem is just that you don't have a reference to the stage, you can get it inside the handler with `btn.getScene().getWindow()`

Comment: Those scenes look similar if not the same except for the image displayed in the `ImageView`. Are you sure the scene needs to be replaced? Wouldn't `view.setImage(newImage);` suffice? As for accessing the `Stage`: You could simply add a method parameter that you could use to pass the `Stage` or a different object that allows sufficient access to the functionality you reqire. You could also assume the scene is used with the stage in question and use James_D's approach.